# How to perform Basic Authentication in C# Selenium ChromeDriver and run the build on TeamCity

Tags: c#, selenium, authentication, teamcity

I am doing website automation testing and am stuck with entering basic authentication credentials in C# using ChromedDriver, I have searched a lot of old posts and tried different approaches, but I haven't found anything working for me.

1. There are some old post to enter UserName Password in URL, i.e
   this.driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(http://username:password@TestURL), But this has been stopped supported by Chrome.
2. I tried to use AutoIt, it works locally but doesn't work on TeamCity build, looks like it requires TeamCity to run on console mode (not service mode), which is not an option for my situation.

   ```
       AutoItX.Send(MyUserName);
       AutoItX.Send("{TAB}");
       AutoItX.Send(MyPassword);
       AutoItX.Send("{Enter}");
   ```
3. Another approach is using WinAppDriver, again, it works on my local Windows 10 PC, but it's doesn't support Window 7, 8 or Windows 2012 server, so it's not an option for me.

Could anyone please help if you have working solutions?